# Given a web page and a line segment (0x, 10px), (100px, 200px), what is the easiest way to find all dom elements that intersect with that line?

Tags: javascript, dom, webkit, gecko, blink

I'm building a visual editing tool in the browser.

In my tool, the user can draw a random line between any 2 points on the page.

Point A could be at 0px, 100px. Point B could be at 50px, 200px.

I want to find all DOM elements that are intersected by that line.

What's the best way to do this?

For example:

`var elements = queryByLine(0, 10, 50, 200) // x1, y1, x2, y1`

Expected (an array of dom elements):

`$(elements).addClass('intersected')`

Comment: How do you display the elements? With `position: absolute` or does it vary?

Comment: So you want us to make your homework?